# Fade out div when it collides with next div in parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 `divs` containing text and an image. I've set their position to `sticky`. My idea was to fade out the top div as soon as the bottom div collides with it.

The general idea I have to execute this is to create a special css class called "is-gone" that basically sets the opacity to 0 and then uses the fades out using CSS (using `transition: opacity 0.5s ease`) and then write a JS that detects collision between the nth and (n+1)th child and then applies a `is-gone` class to n.

I can't figure out, however, how to detect collision. I've tried some JavaScripts where I loop through each div, get its `y`, add its height and then check once the next div's `y` goes beyond that value. But I can't even get the code to print the value in the console hahaha

**Update:**

Here is the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/nicobaguio/0hgr3r63/15/) of the answer with some help from Edward Kotarski.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic solution for detecting intersection between two divs is:

```
intersects(elementA, elementB) {
   var a = elementA.getBoundingClientRect();
   var b = elementB.getBoundingClientRect();
   return !((b.left > a.right) ||
           (b.right < a.left) ||
           (b.top > a.bottom) ||
           (b.bottom < a.top));
}
```

^This works by detecting any case where the elements don't overlap, and inverting the result.

Write a loop which iterates through each n,n+1 pair (you were on the right track with this), checks the intersect with this function, and triggers the fade.

You probably want to put the whole loop in the onScroll (or something) event.

Comment: so basically I create a function that checks if two JS objects are intersecting. Then inside a on('scroll', ...) event, I trigger an entire loop each time? Wouldn't that be too inefficient?

Comment: If you wrap the existing divs in a parent and put the scroll event on that (rather than the document) it will fire less often. Unless you have hundreds of child divs the computer will barely notice.

Comment: ahh yeah. let me implement that. hold on.

Comment: I did it! Thank you. Let me update my question! Thank you!

Comment: If you are happy then please accept my answer as the answer :)